# iOS - TBXML - Get ALL <img>-tags

Tags: iphone, ios, tbxml

I tried to start with TBXML, but I don't understand how it works...

How can I get ALL img-tags (as TBXMLElement) from a document?

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the guide? Start from [here](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Loading_an_XML_document.html) and then proceed [here](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html). You mentioned that you are trying to retrieve only a certain tag type from your document but did not post your overall structure or any example code. If you want more detailed help then you will have to post a more detailed question.